# NGO library Removal

Tags: shapefile, arcobjects, c#, schematics

NGO library is not available anymore, thats where my question comes in, those objects at bottom in code section, mean nothing because there is no reference for them in arcobjects v10.. this is what they have written on the website regarding this matter.

> In prior versions, NGO engine was the graphical core. It handled the
>   set of primitive objects for loading schematic diagrams in memory,
>   displaying schematic diagrams, managing symbology, labeling and
>   layout, and editing schematic diagrams. In the current version, NGO
>   engine is removed from Schematics.Consequently, INg interfaces and Ng
>   coclasses no longer exist. There are now equivalent interfaces.

so I am trying to figure out what those "equivalent interfaces" are. Please take a look at this example where I have a bunch of objects that are not available in version 10..

```c#
{
private string _diagramPrefix;
private ISchematicAnalystFindConnected _findConnectedAlgo;
private ISchematicDataset _project;
private ISchematicRelationController _relController;
private ISchematicRelationControllerEdit _relControllerEdit;
private ISchematicRelationControllerTool _relControllerTool;
private ScaleLinkHelpers _scaleHelper;
private INgView _view;
private ISchematicInMemoryFeatureNodes _nodes;
INgUserDatas udas = new NgUserDatasClass();
INgUserData d1 = new NgUserDataClass();    
private INgPoint boundaryPoint;    
private NgFlag currentFlag;
private   INgValues vals = new NgValuesClass();
}
```

Comment: What does Esri's non-use of this library have to do with the question? This is more a matter of software development (and compiler use) which might be more appropriate elsewhere in the Stack Exchange hierarchy. They will expect a better worded question, with the actual error messages generated by the compiler, and information on where the library is installed, and the steps you took to modify the include and library paths appropriately.

Comment: this library is not available no more, thats where my question comes, those objects mean nothing because there is no reference for them in arcobjects v10.. this is what they have written on the website.In prior versions, NGO engine was the graphical core. It handled the set of primitive objects for loading schematic diagrams in memory, displaying schematic diagrams, managing symbology, labeling and layout, and editing schematic diagrams.
In the current version, NGO engine is removed from Schematics.Consequently, INg interfaces and Ng coclasses no longer exist. There r now equivalent interfaces

Comment: so I am trying to figure out what those "equivalent interfaces" are.

Comment: Then you should edit the question to actually ask this (both comments, without the typos and formatting issues)

Comment: Have you seen the ArcObjects [What's New at 10](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualHelp/#/What_s_new_at_10/0001000002zp000000/) topic that discusses the changes?

Comment: yes I have, does not answer my question. anything that starts with "INg" is no more. and I have 7 tools that use the INg library. If I can upgrade one of them to V10, then I can do the rest, but I am unable to get the code to compile or run, because the assymbly does not contain reference for the INg library because it was removed in versions prior to 9.3

Comment: sorry I meant to say th library was only present in versions prior to 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very old and pointless. 
It was silly of me to ask this question to begin with since the entire schematics engine prior to 10 was based on graphics, where the later version changed that into Schematic Feature Classes, instead of Graphical Elements.

Some of the interfaces remained, while the rest was replaced.